# SML finding a sum of squares/halves using other functions

Tags: algorithm, sml, smlnj

So I want to find the sum of applying function f to the first n integers, when the sum of applying f to the first n integers is f applied to n plus the sum of applying f to the first n-1 integers, as in:

```
- fun inc x = x+1;
> val inc = fn : inet -> int
- sumF inc 3;
> 9 : int i.e. inc 3+inc 2+ inc 1+ 0
```

and my sumF looks like this now:

```
- fun sumF 0 = 0 | sumF n = sumF(n) + sumF(n-1);
val sumF = fn : int -> int
- sumF inc 3;
stdIn:15.1-15.11 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int
  operand:         int -> int
  in expression:
    sumF inc
```

As you can see I get an error, so maybe anyone knows how to fix it? Because later on, I want to write sumSq (sumSq n = (n*n) + sumSq(n-1))  and sumHalf (sumSq n = (n*n) + sumSq(n-1)), using sumF.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
fun sumF f 0 = 0
  | sumF f n = f n + sumF f (n - 1)
```

Your problem is, that you don't actually use the `inc` function in the definition of `sumF` function. You define the `sumF` function with only one argument of type int, but then you call this function with "two arguments". Your function call `sumF inc 3` is interpreted as `((sumF inc) 3)`, and since the type of `inc` is int -> int, but the function expects the argument of type int, you get the error. And, besides this, your function has an additional problem - it creates infinite loop, since you call `sumF n` in the definition of `sumF n`.

You can call the function above as

```
- fun inc x = x + 1;
val inc = fn : int -> int
- sumF inc 3;
val it = 9 : int
```

or a bit shorter with anonymous function:

```
- sumF (fn x => x + 1) 3;
val it = 9 : int
```

Regards, Špela